# Reading JSON from HTTP Post request using java

Tags: json, post

Can anyone cite an (java) example how to access a JSON which is sent in body of a HTTP POST request?

So I have `HttpServletRequest req` and this is working but converting entire thing to a string.

```
while (line != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
    line = reader.readLine();
}
reader.close();
String data = sb.toString();
```

How to use JSON here?
Please let me know if there is any example.

Comment: There's too few info in the question. You have to include at least how your JSON response looks like...

Comment: Why are you adding the extra newline?